# Torelli theorem for stable vector bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, moduli-spaces

Let $X, X^{\prime}\colon$ smooth projective curve on $\mathbb{C}$ (genus $\geq 3$),
$M(r,d)\colon$ coarse moduli of stable vector bundles with rank $r\geq2$, and degree $d$ , and
$M(r,\xi)\colon$ coarse moduli of stable vector bundles which have fixed determinant $\xi$ with rank $r$.

In other words, define
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{det}\colon &M(r,d)&\rightarrow &\operatorname{Jac}^{d}(X)\\
&E&\mapsto&\wedge^{r} E
\end{eqnarray}
then,
\begin{equation}
M(r,\xi)=\operatorname{det}^{-1}(\xi)
\end{equation}

There is a famous fact,
$M(r,\xi)_{X}\cong M(r,\xi^{\prime})_{X^{\prime}}$ then $X\cong X^{\prime}$.

I want to know whether $M(r,d)_{X}\cong M(r,d)_{X^{\prime}}$ implies $X\cong X^{\prime}$.
I think it is possible to prove that by almost the same proof.

But if not, why I must consider fixed determinant ? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: When $r$ and $d$ are relatively prime, I think this follows from rationalality of the fibers of $M(r,d)\rightarrow\operatorname{Jac}^d(X)$ (which I think is proven in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9907068). In that case the map to $\operatorname{Jac}^d(X)$ is the Albanese map of $M(r,d)$ and so if the $M(r,d)$ are the same so are the $M(r,\xi)$. I am not sure what happens when $r$ and $d$ are not relatively prime.

Answer (score 7):

As dhy said, this follows if we know that the fibers $M(r,\xi)$ are rational. In fact, it suffices to know that they are unirational - we can deduce that their image in any map to an abelian variety is a point, hence any map from $M(r,d)$ to an abelian variety factors through the determinant map, and thus the Albanese of $M(r,d)$ is $\operatorname{Jac}^d$.

Their unirationality is not so hard to prove.

Take $L$ ample enough that $V \otimes L$ is globally generated for every stable vector bundle of rank $r$ and determinant $\xi$. (It suffices to have $H^1( X, V \otimes L (-P)) =0$ for all points $P$, i.e. it suffices to have $H^0(X, V^\vee \otimes K_X \otimes L^{\vee} (P))$, so it suffices to have $\deg L > 2g-1 + \frac{ \deg xi}{r}$.)

Then among maps  $(L^{-1})^{n-1} \to V$, those which have rank $< n-1$ at a point $P$ form a codimension $2$ subset, so those which have rank $<n-1$ at any point form a codimension $1$ subset, and thus there exists a map $(L^{-1})^{n-1} \to V$ with full rank at every point. Hence the quotient is a line bundle, which because $\det V = \xi$, must be $ \xi \otimes L^{\otimes (n-1)}$. So $V$ is an extension of $\xi \otimes L^{\otimes (n-1)}$ by $(L^{-1})^{n-1}$.

Now there is an open subset of $\operatorname{Ext}^1 ( \xi \otimes L^{\otimes (n-1)}, (L^{-1})^{n-1} )$ parameterizing stable vector bundles, which maps to $M(r,\xi)$. By the above argument this map is surjective, so $M(r,\xi)$ is unirational.